# UpdatePanel - Always e conditional juntos

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net

Tenho uma duvida.
É possível disparar evento somente no updatePanel conditional sendo que ele está dentro de outro que não é conditional?
Segue o exemplo:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPagina">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelGridView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnInserirGrid" EventName="Click" />                           
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>                           
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o que era.

Criei o metodo onInit e inseri o

```
scriptmanager1.EnablePartialRendering = false;
```

Resolveu.